# Как отправлять запросы через прокси без дополнительного заголовка?

Tags: php, curl, proxy, прокси

При отправке и получении запросов через прокси к ним добавляется от проксирующего сервера дополнительный заголовок:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
```

Отсюда вопрос, как можно отправлять запросы через cURL (PHP) без добавления этого заголовка? Есть какие-нибудь cURL-параметры, которые запрещают выставлять проксирующему серверу свой заголовок?

Если же убрать заголовки нельзя, то может ли получатель запроса определить, что он пришел через прокси, а не напрямую? То есть в запросе будет 2 заголовка вида:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Comment: этот заголовок добавляется к запросу, а не ответу?

Comment: @teran вот это я и пытаюсь понять, ответы приходят с двойным заголовком, полагаю то же самое происходит при получении запросов сервером. экспериментировал для разных прокси, заголовок везде один и тот же.

Comment: 200 это код ответа, к запросам он не относится вообще никак. Вы должны получать ответ от прокси, что туннель установлен, а потом ответ от конечного сервера. Конечный сервер знать не знает о прокси. для проверки отправьте запрос на свой же сайт через этот прокси и просмотрите  входящие заголовки через `apache_request_headers ()`

Comment: @teran да, apache_request_headers () то, что нужно сейчас проведу эксперимент с собственным сервером.

Comment: @teran провел эксперимент, действительно в headers только эта информация {"Host":"site.com","X-Real-IP":"XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX","Connection":"close","Accept":"*\/*"} меняется только IP-адрес. получается это единственная информация, которую сервер получает от отправляющего канала?

Comment: при запросе через браузер то поболее заголовков будет, но коли вы через cURL запрашиваете, то больше там быть  нечему, кроме того что вы сами формируете

Comment: @teran ну тогда это именно то, что нужно)) спасибо! дальше уже буду ставить эксперименты с вариациями заголовков.

Comment: @teran да, посмотрел что приходит через браузер, в целом все стандартно. более чем можно эмулировать через cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу определения получателем заголовков запроса выяснил опытным путем, что там приходит только то, что ему посылается через cURL (при этом можно эмулировать полноценный запрос от браузера). Соответственно, определить проксирование со стороны сервера не представляется возможным.

Что касается добавления заголовка к ответу, перешел на использование SOCKS5. Там проксирующий сервер ничего от себя не добавляет к ответу.